# How to install SSRS when SQL Server is already installed?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How to install SSRS when SQL Server is already installed? I tried running `SQLEXPRWT_x64` again to add SSRS feature, but Reporting tick box doesn't appear (screenshot below). Could anyone please help?

[image: Adding Feature to existing Install]

[image: SSRS Reporting feature is missing]

Comment: are they on same version?

Comment: Hi, yes they both are SQL 2014 Express. It is deployed in AWS cloud instance by the way. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: I dont know if SSRS is in express edition. You might want to check that first.

Comment: If you want SSRS in an Express edition, you must use the SQL Server **Express with Advanced Services** subedition. Did you download that one?

Comment: I have not tried 2014. Will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlknowledge.com/2014/04/sql-2014-express-edition-limitations/

I think you need to run the right executable as per link

> SQL 2014 Express edition is free and great head start for small
>   applications or learning purposes. SQL 2014 express is available in 5
>   variants for more flexibility; its self explanatory names are given
>   below. Each has nearly similar features and limitations except
>   followings. Check the references for detailed list. **Express with
>   Advanced Services (SQLEXPRADV) with features like :Reporting Services
>   feature**, Full-text and semantic search, Specification of language in
>   query SQL Server Management Studio Express (SQLManagementStudio)
>   Express with Tools (SQLEXPRWT) Express (SQLEXPR) LocalDB (SqlLocalDB)
>   a very light weighted edition for development purposes.

Comment: wow.. we are not spoon-feeding here dude! you need to read and understand.

Comment: I happen to agree with Dijkgraaf. Answers on SO must be useful even if links die. If your link dies, there isn't a lot left to this answer and it would probably have been better to be a comment. (I didn't downvote you btw.)

Comment: noted with thanks DeanOC...... @Dijkgraaf i can appreciate if you comment first before downvoting me.

Comment: Most people when they downvote will not leave a comment, because then the sometimes get revenge downvotes.  It was not me either that downvoted you, I was just speculating is to why they may have

Comment: right... downvoting is just rude but you know.. just learnt a lesson today. regards

Comment: Thank you maSTA rHiAn for your reply. That helps. I am sure who and why they have down voted the question but that was a genuine problem.